# Any Daisy-3 book readers for Java/Android?

Tags: java, android

We are trying to develop an Android based text reader for books in Daisy3 (http://www.daisy.org/z3986/structure/SG-DAISY3/index.html) format. Currently we are only focusing on rendering the text part and not on the audio (daisy3 format has both text and audio, primarily for users with reading disabilities).

I want to know if there already are any efforts going on in this regard.
I know that there is Daisy2 android project (http://code.google.com/p/android-daisy-epub-reader/). However, we want to develop for Daisy 3 standard, which is structurally different from Daisy2.

I would also like to know if there are any Java based text readers for Daisy3 format which can serve as a reference?
Any pointers/help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although theoretically the DTBOOK markup (for the text content) can be styled with CSS in supporting web-browsers, or even dynamically transformed with XSLT, in reality it is common practice to transform the DTBOOK to plain old HTML when opening the DAISY book. There's a standalone XSLT transformer available as part of the DAISY Pipeline open-source production tool:

http://data.daisy.org/projects/pipeline/doc/scripts/DTBookToXhtml.html

Cheers, Dan

Comment: This approach sounds interesting. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

[Emerson](http://code.google.com/p/emerson-reader/) is an open-source, desktop software reader/player, based on the Eclipse-RCP-Java development framework.